# Lazy loading after page reload cannot find some module declarations

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

My app consists of

- Route /home -> app module
- Route /dashboard -> Dashboard module
- Route /profile -> profile module
- Route /event -> event module
- Route /services -> services module

I am using lazy loading and all works well

All navigation combinations after a page reload work well. Not matter from where to where.

Eg:

Profile -> Dashboard 
Services -> Dashboard 
Home -> Dashboard 
etc

But only after a page reload one navigation does not work:

event -> Dashboard doesn't work only! All other routing after page reload works !

I get errors of

```
breadcrumbs.js:64 ERROR Error: Template error: Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'app-timeline-chart'.
```

Here is my code:

appModule

```
declare function require(moduleName: string): any;

const {version: appVersion} = require('../../package.json');

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'https://e6aa6074f13d49c299f8c81bf162d88c@sentry.io/1194244',
  environment: environment.production ? 'Production' : 'Development',
  release: appVersion,
});


@Injectable()
export class SentryErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor() {
  }

  handleError(error) {
    // Sentry.showReportDialog({ eventId });
    // const eventId = Sentry.captureException(error.originalError || error);
    console.log(error);
    Sentry.captureException(error)
  }
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence({synchronizeTabs: true}),
    AngularFireFunctionsModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirePerformanceModule,
    MaterialModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SideNavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    EventFormComponent,
    ActivityFormComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    EventFormComponent,
    ActivityFormComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    // {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: SentryErrorHandler}
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: environment.production ? SentryErrorHandler : ErrorHandler},
    {provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: MatPaginatorIntlFireStore},
    {provide: FunctionsRegionToken, useValue: 'europe-west2'}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

And the dashboardModule

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    MaterialModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    UploadComponent,
    UploadInfoComponent,
    ChartsPieComponent,
    ChartsXYComponent,
    ChartsTimelineComponent,
    SummariesComponent,
    ChartActionsComponent,
    EventSearchComponent,
    EventsExportFormComponent,
    EditInputComponent,
    UploadErrorComponent,
    ActivityMetadataComponent,
    EventTableComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    UploadErrorComponent,
    EventsExportFormComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})



export class DashboardModule { }
```

As you saw on the error the specific component `ChartsTimelineComponent,`  used that it errors on not finding it, if I move it to a shared component does not fail.

However, that is silly because only dashboard component uses it, and if there was no page reload or navigation from another module all works fine.

Any clue?

I know its very hard what I am asking , it might be even an angular bug but I am mainly searching for any clues , or where to turn my neck to.

After some investigation the question is more about

App.module 
ChildA.module 
ChildB.module

ChildA and ChildB have components that base on the same abstract class meaning that they both eg have

ComponentForChildA, ComponentForChildB and they base on ComponentAbstractClass

Comment: In which component are you calling `app-timeline-chart` ? Where is your `breadcrumb.js` ?

Comment: First of all pull the SharedModule from AppModule, it is the only place where you should not have it imported because then you make it global and it defeats the purpose of having it in other modules. Second, check if the ChartsTimelineComponent is only used within the components that are declared in DashboardModule, and also what does breadcrumbs.js has to do with this? is That makes me think that there is another reference of your ChartsTimelineComponent outside of the Dashboard

Comment: I am kinda on to this issue. Thanks guys. Here is the deal, both child modules (dasboard and event) load components that are based on an common abstract. 
The components are different. Eg 'xy-chart' for the dashboard module, and `event-chart` on the event  module. Removing eg the event-chart from the event module resolves this. 

So the question is: 

What should one do with modules and their components that share the same abstract class.

Comment: @NerijusPamedytis done that thanks for the tip right forgot that

Comment: Also breadcrumbs is sentry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to IVY and the inheritance issue as described here https://hackmd.io/@alx/S1XKqMZeS

I had abstract classes that did not have any decorators.

Adding the decorators via upgrading to Angular 9 (migration) solved this